# How do I share files with someone who does not have a ubuntu one account

Tags: ubuntu-one, file-sharing

I tried to search for an answer, except that, uhhh there is no search.

I want to share a Ubuntu One folder with people who do not have a Ubuntu One account.  Is that possible?

I found this answer in the faq, "Yes! Since Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Ubuntu One supports sharing files publicly. Right click on a file already synchronized by Ubuntu One and select "Publish via Ubuntu One". Right-click on the file again and select "Copy Ubuntu One public URL". You can now paste the URL and share it with whoever you want."

That doesn't seem to help me with 11.04.  There is no 'Publish via Ubuntu One' button in 11.04.

Does anyone know if there is a way to share files with non-ubuntu users?  If so, how?

Thanks In Advance,
Bob

Comment: No search? What about the top right corner (of askubuntu)?

Answer (score 3):

There are two options here:

1. Place the files you want to share in a folder under `~/Ubuntu One`.  Right click on the folder and pick `Share...` from the `Ubuntu One` menu.  Enter their email address in the resulting window and create the share.  The recipient will need to create an Ubuntu One account to accept the share.
2. Place the files under `~/Ubuntu One`.  Right click on the file you want to share and pick `Publish` from the `Ubuntu One` menu.  A notification bubble will show up displaying the URL the file has been shared to.

While the second option requires less work on the part of the recipient, it makes the file available to the general public.  If you wish the files to remain private, pick the first option.  If the recipient does not use Ubuntu, they will still be able to access the files via Ubuntu One's web interface.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  I have a folder in the Ubuntu One folder that I would like to share.  From your response, I'm guessing that I can't share the folder.  It has 38 files in it.  Do I need to send 38 URLs to the people that I want to share these files with?  Also,where can I find the url that the file has been shared to after the bubble disappears?

Comment: The "Publish" option is intended for publishing individual files, so if you wanted to use that option you would end up with 38 URLs to share.  Although with that many files the first option may suit you better.  As I mentioned, the recipient can easily set up an account as part of the process of accepting the share.  As for discovering the public URL of a file after publishing it, right click on it and choose the `Copy Web Link` option from the `Ubuntu One` submenu.  The URL will now be on the clipboard ready to paste into another application.

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt response.  I thought Ubuntu One was like what Apple users refer to as 'The Cloud', where you can easily share files with people.  Oh Well, I mainly wanted offsite backup anyways.  It would be nice to be able to easily share files in the future if that's possible.

Comment: Well, I explained how you'd be able to share an entire folder by just entering the email addresses of the people you wanted to share with (the first option).  That method doesn't require any work on your part to share new files, and makes it easy to revoke access to individuals should the need arise.  And as I said, it doesn't require that the recipient be using Ubuntu: the web interface can be used from any platform, and there is a Windows client in development if they prefer better integration on that platform.